# toggle divs left property on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="slide_item"></div>
<div id="wrapper" data-cycle-slides="div" data-cycle-log="true"></div>
```

the `#wrapper` is hidden because `#slide_item` is above that div. What I intend to do is using `#slide_item` as a button to change the `left` property of `#wrapper`

My attempt was:

```
$('#slide_item').click(function () {
    $("#wrapper").toggle(function() { 
        $(this).animate({left: 150}, 500);
    }, function() { 
        $(this).animate({left: 0}, 500);
    });
});
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** `.toggle()` was removed since jQuery 1.9, anyone knows the alternative method?

Comment: What jQuery version you're using? Please note that `.toggle()` event has been removed since version `1.9`

Comment: @Felix oh yeah, I'm using 1.10, but why did they remove it and whats the alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just check the current left position?

```
$('#slide_item').click(function () {
    var wrap = $('#wrapper')
    if (wrap.css('left')=='150px') {
        $(this).animate({left: 0}, 500);
    } else if (wrap.css('left')=='0px') {
        $(this).animate({left: 150}, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working as expected have a look

```
$('#slide_item').click(function () {
    $("#wrapper").toggle(function() { 
        $(this).animate({left: 150}, 500);
    }, function() { 
        $(this).animate({left: 0}, 500);
    });
});
```

Demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/u97Ja/10/

Comment: look comments above, seems it is because my jQuery version is 1.10

Comment: but what's the alternative method? I don't see any point why they did remove it and have no alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner for fun ;)

```
$('#slide_item').click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").animate({ left: $("#wrapper").css("left") === "0px" ? 150 : 0 });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4LUC/